# Using GIT to update files on local fileserver

Tags: git, filesystems, windows-server-2003

OK so I have a repo setup on my machine and I'm looking to use this to push updates to a location on a fileserver. I used the following to clone:

Starting in dir on machine:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial'
cd ../
```

Then cloning onto fileserver

```
git clone -bare testdir fileserverip/testdir
```

This clones fine but how can I use GIT to update? Unlike my previous experience with GIT I'm not looking to connect over SSH or anything so how can I set up the push?

EDIT:

After modifying my setup as mentioned in the answer by **Makis** I get the following errors on `git push`

```
james-macbook:test2 james$ git push
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 506 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
james-macbook:test2 james$
```

Anyone know what this means?

EDIT: Just found this, think it's what I need. http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/creating-local-git-repositories-yeah-its-that-simple/

Thanks

Comment: Just thought this might be more appropriate on ServerFault. Not sure?

Comment: The problem looks like your remote repo isn't bare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can mount the server directory via NFS or Samba, easy peasy. I would have created the bare repository on the server first. Then clone the empty repository on your machine and add the stuff.

After that, everything works like normal (pull, push).

Comment: Do you know why pull and push doesn't seem to update removing or renaming files? The git status says it is on push but when I pull down it pulls the renamed file and keeps the old one too :/

Comment: You have to use git rm to remove files from the repository instead of git add.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to do something very similar to the common question of deploying a website by pushing to a git repository so information on how to do that should equally apply to this situation.

http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

That webpage describes setting up a bare repository (FYI in the command you listed above you had `-bare` instead of `--bare` which could be one problem you are encountering) and using a post-receive hook to update the contents of a directory automatically. The post-receive hook does this by calling `git checkout -f` but with an explicit work tree specified (bare repositories don't have work trees so normally that command would fail).

Comment: Thanks, I actually ment -- but I got it working in the end. Thanks.